# How to escape pipe character from PowerShell command line to pass into non-PowerShell command

Tags: shell, powershell, command-line, escaping

I'm in a PowerShell console session, trying to run a Gradle script that exists in the `cwd` from the PowerShell command line.

The Gradle command accepts an argument which includes quotes that can contain one or more pipe characters, and I can't for the life of me figure out how to get PowerShell to escape it using just one line (or any number of lines, actually - but I'm not interested in multi-line solutions).

Here's the command:

```
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing|thatThing|theOtherThing"
```

...which produces this error:

```
'thatThing' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I've tried all of these variants, none of which work. Any idea?

```
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing`|thatThing`|theOtherThing"
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty=@"thisThing|thatThing|theOtherThing"
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing\|thatThing\|theOtherThing"
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing\\|thatThing\\|theOtherThing"
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing^|thatThing^|theOtherThing"
```

Comment: Have you tried `^|` ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: yes. I'll add that to the list. I think that's a DOS shell escape character

Comment: Sorry, that was guesswork. I however have tried this `echo theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing|thatThing|theOtherThing"`` and the echo command works properly (windows 10). Can you try?

Comment: Yes, that echoes back the arguments that appear after 'echo'. But, i need for it to run the gradle script that is in the cwd with those same arguments

Comment: so the problem must reside in the gradle script. Have you tried printing some stuff right at the start of your script?

Comment: I can absolutely verify that this is not coming from the gradle script. The gradle script is not being executed. The error message is coming from the shell, before the script ever gets executed.

Comment: oh wait - it may not be the gradle script, but it can be the gradlew.bat script that launches the gradle script. I'll bet that's where the problem lies. I'll check into that. Thanks!

Comment: Confirmed: you're right, it's in gradlew.bat where it sets the command line args using `set CMD_LINE_ARGS=%*`

Answer (score 3):

Well, I have found that:

First call your script like this as I first suggested:

```
./gradlew theTask -PmyProperty="thisThing^|thatThing^|theOtherThing"
```

Then modify your gradlew.bat script by adding quotes:

```
set CMD_LINE_ARGS="%*"
```

The problem is: now CMD_LINE_ARGS must be called within quotes or the same error will occur.

So I assume that your command line arguments cannot be something else and I'm handling each parameter one by one

```
rem now remove the quotes or there will be too much quotes
set ARG1="%1"
rem protect or the pipe situation will occur
set ARG1=%ARG1:""=%
set ARG2="%2"
set ARG2=%ARG2:""=%
set ARG3="%3"
set ARG3=%ARG3:""=%

echo %ARG1% %ARG2% %ARG3%
```

The output is (for my mockup command):

```
theTask -PmyProperty "thisThing|thatThing|theOtherThing"
```

The "=" has gone, because it has separated parameters from PowerShell. I suppose this won't be an issue if your command has standard argument parsing.

Add as many arguments as you want, but limit it to 9 anyway.

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't any pattern I can rely on for the command line argument list, it will have a variable number of arguments and I won't know ahead of time which, if any, of the arguments might need escaping

Comment: I've applied my change on all args, that should be better.

Comment: Thank you for your help - ultimately, the solution lies in a [bug report](https://issues.gradle.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa) to the gradle team, as I don't own the development of the script.

Answer (score -1):

Found another possibility [here](https://octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping). One can use single quotes and double quotes like this. Not sure if that helps to solve the original problem but it helped to solve mine.

`'"thisThing|thatThing|theOtherThing"'`

Comment: Unrelated. The problem is with the pipe characters, not the quotes.